# My request is responding with a 404 error yet it is posted as supposed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sendgrid, contact-form

Please I am trying to create a contact from using express and sendGrid. Everything seems to work fine but for some reason I get a 404 error on the request but the messages delivers as intended. I do not understand how I am getting a 404 error on the request yet the messages are sending well. My code!!

```
Front-End Code 
const [message, setMessage] = useState({
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    email: "",
    website: "",
    subject: "",
    message: "",
    email_sent: null,
    disable: false,
  });
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Axios.post("/api/email", message).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.data.success === true) {
        setMessage({
          disable: false,
          email_sent: true,
        });
      } else {
        setMessage({
          disable: false,
          email_sent: false,
        }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
      }
    });

Back-End Code.

const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const sendGrid = require("@sendgrid/mail");
const { restart } = require("nodemon");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/api", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("API STATUS: RUNNING");
  next();
});

app.post("/api/email", (req, res, next) => {
  sendGrid.setApiKey(
    "myAPIkey goes here"
  );
  const msg = {
    to: "email I am sending to goes here",
    from: "mysendGrid Verified sender email goes here",
    email: req.body.email,
    subject: req.body.subject,
    text: req.body.message,
  };
  sendGrid
    .send(msg)
    .then((result) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error:", err.toString());
      res.status(401).json({
        success: false,
      });
    });
  next();
});

app.listen(5000);

Thank you.
```

Comment: You should `return` in your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.send()` method. like this:

```
.then(result => {
  res.status(200).send({success : true});
})
```

Hope this has solved the issue :-)

Comment: Great. Please accept this answer if it has helped you resolve the issue. Thank you.